# Do I need to destroy CreationalContext used in BeanManager.getReference?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

There is something I do not understand with `CreationalContext` and `BeanManager.getReference` in CDI.

I'm using CDI 1.2 with Wildfly 8.2.1, and here is my problem.

I have a CDI bean  which is produced by a third-party library.

The bean :

```
public class ProducedBean
{
   private long m_id;

   public long getId()
   {
      return m_id;
   }
}
```

And the producer (it's just an example):

```
@Produces
public ProducedBean getBean()
{
   return new ProducedBean();
}
```

In a CDI custom Scope context, I need to access this bean. So I use the `BeanManager` :

```
final Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(ProducedBean.class);
final Bean<?> bean = beanManager.resolve(beans);
CreationalContext<JobContext> creationalContext = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);
final ProducedBean producedBean = (ProducedBean) beanManager.getReference(bean, ProducedBean.class, creationalContext);
// Get id of ProducedBean
// Then release creationalContext?
```

I have 2 questions regarding this code :

1°) Do I need to destroy the `creationalContext` after `ProducedBean` creation? I read the javadoc but it is not clear to me. I just want to get the id of `ProducedBean`.

2°) Is it better to use `beanManager.createCreationalContext(null)` or `beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean)`? In my case I just read the id of `ProducedBean`.

Thanks.

Comment: For the record, with WildFly 10, you are (by default) using CDI 1.2.

Comment: Actully it's wildfly 8, i will correct my post. Thanks for notocing the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your bean is (I hope intentionally) `@Dependent` which afflicts the way you need to handle it. For `@Dependent` you have one instance per injection and it is destroyed once you destroy the contextual bean which injected it. Therefore in your case, you will want to handle this manually.

Now, to you specific questions:

1. No need to handle the *context* itself. Instead, once you are done working with your `ProducedBean` go back to `Bean<ProducedBean>` object and make sure you call its `destroy(T instance, CreationalContext<T> creationalContext)` method. Again, you need to do this, because your bean is `@Dependent`.
2. You will most likely want to use `beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean)`. The reason being that if your `ProducedBean` has any (contextual) dependencies, e.g. injects other stuff, this will resolve the injections. With null, it is only good for unmanaged instanced if I recall correctly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's very clear. For point 2, as I kown how is produced the `ProducedBean`, why shouldn't I use `beanManager.createCreationalContext(null)` instead of `beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean)`? I mean I know that `ProducedBean` does not have any injected bean, so there's no need to resolve any injection, no?

Comment: Your question did not imply that there are no contextual dependencies. If that's the case, you might be just fine using calling the method with `null` I think.

Comment: ok, thanks. It's right that my initial post is not very clear about what returns the producer. Sorry for that. However I tested using `beanManager.createCreationalContext(null)` on another bean which has injected dependencies and those one are correctly injected. So I still do not understand in which case the `beanManager.createCreationalContext(null)` is used for. Anyway, thanks for your help! :-)